# Frequency dependence of far field condition

Tags: acoustics, wavelength, resonance

I am analyzing accelerometer data collected at a drill rig, at the top of the drill string. The drill bit acts an acoustic source; the acoustic waves travel through the drill pipe from the bit to the sensor.

[image]

Based on Aki & Richards (1980), far field begins when the distance from source to receiver r exceeds "many wavelengths". Other authors (*e.g.* Poletto *et al.*, 2020) express the transition between far field and near field as r~$\lambda$/2$\pi$.

Considering a peak frequency f<sub>peak</sub> of 2Hz (consistent with the drill's rotational speed of 120rpm) and compressional velocity c of 5,000m/s in steel, I find the wavelength $\lambda$:

$\lambda$=c/f<sub>peak</sub>=5000/2=2500m.

For a source-receiver distance r of 40m, r<$\lambda$ (and also r<$\lambda$/2$\pi$): the far field condition is not met.

However, I am also interested in the drill string's resonance frequency. Let's assume in this example that f<sub>resonance</sub> is 120Hz. This leads to:

$\lambda$=c/f<sub>resonance</sub>=5000/120=41.66m.

In this example, r~$\lambda$ and r>$\lambda$/2$\pi$.

How can this result be interpreted?

1. Should I understand that the measured signal is a mix between near and far field signals?
2. Is it even relevant to consider the source-recever distance r when dealing with the resonance frequency? After all, the source of the 120Hz signal is no longer the drill bit but the pipe itself, oscillating at its resonance frequency.

Comment: Do you happen to have any recorded signals from this setup? I am curious about them and maybe they can provide some info or insight. Just saying...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @ZaellixA. Alas, I am working with proprietary data that I am not allowed to share.

Comment: Hey, now worries. I understand, I was just curious to see what they would like and what kind of signals you were recording. Hope you did find an answer to your problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bottom Line Up Front**: There is no far field for your problem.

The "far field" is a feature of homogeneous two- and three-dimensional background domains, whereas your system is effectively one-dimensional.  In the "far field" the acoustic energy propagates only radially away from the source region.  In one-dimensional systems all energy propagates in that dimension, and so either the entire domain is the far field or none of it is the far field.  Furthermore, since your domain is finite, there are going to be reflections from the receiver side of the drill line, so you are going to have energy propagating both ways throughout the entire line, so you *really* should not be thinking of this system in terms of near and far fields.

Now, if the primary signal you were looking at propagated through the earth (i.e., was a seismic wave), you could start thinking about far versus near field behavior, because the earth is a full three-dimensional system.  However, I am guessing that your signal is dominated by the transmission along the line.

**Edit**: Please see the comments for further discussion and (perhaps) clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Michael! You raise a good point: several authors consider receivers located at the ground surface, so the seismic wave originating at the bit effectively travels through a 3D medium before reaching the sensor. 
However, Poletto *et al.*, 2005 claim that "*the near-field effects are important to calculate pilot vibrations* [pilot vibrations are the signals measured at the drill string]", which suggests that it makes sense to think of the drill string in terms of near field / far field.

Comment: *In one-dimensional systems all energy propagates in that dimension, and so either the entire domain is the far field or none of it is the far field*: could you please suggest a reference discussing this in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, after reading your quote in the first comment, I think I understand what they are talking about.  No system is truly one-dimensional; for example, the drill line has a finite radius, albeit much smaller than (a) the length, and (b) the wavelength (probably).  In addition to the propagating plane-wave mode, there are higher-order modes that decay exponentially from the source called evanescent modes.  These modes must be what are referred to.  I don't think I would have called it this, but the "far field" would be beyond where these modes are relevant.

Comment: I don't have a good reference for the "entire domain is far field or none of it is the far field" quote, as I made that connection while I was writing to you.  However, there are many good references for evanescent modes.  A good one is *Fundamentals of Physical Acoustics* by Blackstock (2000) (look in the "Waveguides" chapter).  Although this reference is for waves in air and the wave equation is different from the one you should be using, the basic principles are the same for any acoustic waveguide.